# CoroutineExceptionHandler "swallows" exceptions, but handleException() function isn't called

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When I execute this unit test I see exception notification in the output (probably default exception handler prints it):

```
@Test
fun uncaughtException() {
    runBlocking {
        val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
        val job = scope.launch() {
            delay(100)
            println("inside coroutine")
        }
        scope.launch {
            delay(50)
            throw Exception()
        }
        job.join()
    }
    Thread.sleep(100)
    println("test completed")
}
```

Then I try to add my custom CoroutineExceptionHandler into scope's context:

```
@Test
fun exceptionHandler() {
    runBlocking {
        val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable -> {
            println("Caught exception")
        }}
        val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + exceptionHandler)
        val job = scope.launch() {
            delay(100)
            println("inside coroutine")
        }
        scope.launch {
            delay(50)
            throw Exception()
        }
        job.join()
    }
    Thread.sleep(100)
    println("test completed")
}
```

This makes the previous message about the exception go away (which probably means that my custom handler replaced the default one), but `handleException()` of my custom handler isn't invoked and I don't see "Caught exception" in the output (only "Test completed").

I thought maybe it's something related to unit tests, so I tried this same code in Android app. The result is the same: upon exception the app doesn't crash (which means that the default handler was replaced), but my custom handler's `handleException()` function isn't called.

This feels wrong. Is it the intended behavior or a bug?

Comment: What happens during debugging? or better say when you put a breakpoint in `printLn()`

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher, it's neither triggered in tests, nor in production code.

Comment: can you try that with `runBlockingTest` if it makes a difference?

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher, as I wrote, this behavior reproduces in real Android app, so I don't think it's related to "testing" stuff in any way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crap, I've just wasted an entire hour due to extra pair of curly braces.

I wrote this:

```
    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable -> {
        println("Caught exception")
    }}
```

But the correct way of using that is this:

```
    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        println("Caught exception")
    }
```

Then it works.

Comment: This is unfortunate. Was there no IDE warning?

Comment: @LukasLechner, I don't see any